# How to modify HTML5 form data before validation?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to reuse HTML5 validation `required` in simple serach form (so one input). It's exactly what I need (validation message in browser's language, styling, not allowing to progress, etc.). What I missing is trimming input string so not allowing user to submit just whitespaces.

I made research already and `onsubmit` event seems to be too late triggered to modify anything. I can't also make any change of actual inputs, so those has to remain intact during whole process (like with classic validation).

Is there any way to solve it with vanilla HTML5 without using libs like jQuery?

**Edit**: Using `pattern` attribute is not a solution here because it has different error message than `this field cannot be empty`.

Comment: `pattern=".*[^ ].*"`

Comment: `pattern="[^\s]+"`

Comment: Thanks, but I have edited a question with additional info.

Comment: Yeah, i've updated my answer, you can set a custom error message for the pattern attribute

Answer (score 4):

You could try something along the lines of

```
<form method = "post">
    <input type = "text" required pattern=".*[^ ].*" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please fill out this field')"
    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"/>
    <input type = "submit" />
</form>
```

Otherwise if you really, really need to use only the `required` attribute you something like this would work for you

```
<form method = "post">
    <input type = "text" required oninput = "if(this.value.trim() == '') { this.value = '' }"/>
    <input type = "submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: But I need to provide plenty of translation for it when website is multilingual. That is why I want to reuse `required` feature in a first place - to not bother with translations.

Comment: This works... Look the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/yv1h67jb9tbPeFNVYqxA?p=preview).

Comment: This is more elegant answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onsubmit, You just need to return false if it doesn't validate

```
<form onsubmit="return check()">
  Enter name: <input type="text" id="myinput">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
 function check(){
  if(document.getElementById("myinput").value.trim().length ==0){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: This wouldn't display the error the default way that the browser does it :(